# *Using Eclipse IDE* My button isn't clickable. Python Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, button

I've been trying for about a week now but I can't seem to figure out what I did wrong. My button will not respond when I click it, and even after adding a command it would just display it when I run the program. If I put the disable command, I can see the button change to disabled. Please help if you can.

```
from tkinter import *
screen = Tk()
screen.title = ("My first")
screen.geometry("800x500")

#create a label
myLabel1 = Label(screen, text = "First Program")
myLabel2 = Label(screen, text = "Yeah Buddy")
#place onto screen using grid system
myLabel1.grid(row=0,column=0)
myLabel2.grid(row=1,column=1)
#Create a text box:
txtfield = Entry(screen, width=50, bg="blue", fg= "white")
txtfield.grid(row=2, column =2 )

#command for click (you need to have function appear before where you intend to use it for it to execute.)
def myClick():
    myResponse = Label(screen, text= "Button clicked" + txtfield.get())
    myResponse.grid(row=4, column=2)

#make a button
myButton = Button(screen, text="Test Button", command = myClick())
myButton.grid(row=3, column=2)




screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: `command=myClick()` - > `command=myClick`

Comment: I've removed the [tag:pygame] tag. The [tag:pygame] tag addresses the [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) library, but is not intended for a game written in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling myClick instead of passing the function itself as a parameter. `command=myClick`